# display table and overflow on table cell

Tags: css

How to add overflow on a `table-cell`?

The `table-cell` does not have a fixed size, but it is relative to the total height of the `table` and the upper `table-cell`

http://jsfiddle.net/mgyj1sgk/2/

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell cell_top">Top</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell cell_overflow">
            content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
            content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

/*This table does not have a fixed height (height:100%)*/
.table {
    display:table;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
}
/*This cell does not have a fixed height (could contain multiple lines)*/
.cell_top {
    height:1px;
    min-height:1px;
}
/*This cell must overflow if the height is exceeded*/
.cell_overflow {
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Comment: _“but it is relative to the total height of the table”_ – I don’t see any “relative height” here. `height:1px;` is not relative at all.

Comment: And `overflow` applies to block containers only, http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow

Comment: Instead of complaining about me not being correct.. You could add an answer to my question

Comment: As I said, `overflow` _by defintion_ applies to `block` elements only. Do you _have_ block elements here? No, you don’t, because you specifically made the divs have `display:table-cell`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add child div into table-cell and make overflow stuff there

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell cell_top">Top</div>
        <div class="cell cell_top">Top</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell cell_overflow">
           <div> content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
            content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <b>This cell'c content <br/>defines row's height</b><br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS changes:

```
/*This cell must overflow if the height is exceeded*/
.cell_overflow > div {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[image]

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivangrs/5vt8aja5/)

Comment: Isn't it possible without adding a height to the overflow element? The table has a dynamic height